# Layout in Swift, How to convert topAnchor to heightAnchor

Tags: ios, swift, layout

I am doing some Layout. Here is the code:

```
label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor ).isActive = true
label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor ).isActive = true
label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: view.bounds.size.height * 0.95 - 64).isActive = true
```

The label's `topAnchor` relates to the view's `heightAnchor`.

```
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: view.bounds.size.height * 0.95 - 64).isActive = true
```

Doing math is not advocated, I want to improve the code more intuitive.

I guess there is some way to convert `topAnchor` to `heightAnchor`

---

#### PS:

In fact I am overwritting a Objective-C Sort Algorithm Project in Swift 4.

[Play-With-Sort-OC](https://github.com/MisterBooo/Play-With-Sort-OC)

[image: a]

You see the bottom label . The view above it is mutable array of views.
So the answer is to handle the bottom Anchor in the specific situation.

When I turning the Obj-C code into Swift directly, I want to know if there are some way building relationships between topAnchor and heightAnchor

```
self.timeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0,CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) * 0.95, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40);
self.view addSubview:_timeLabel];
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand why a view's top anchor would be constrained to the height of another view (or vice versa). can you describe or show what you are trying to do? this sounds like it might be overcomplicated and there should be an easier way to do it (maybe not)

Comment: Explain what you are trying to achieve first.

Comment: do you wanna fix it at the bottom of the view?? Just use bottom anchor to bottom of the safe area. you already set the height so no need to set this top anchor